# Gstreamer: Could not swtich codebooks: rtpvorbisdepay

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to stream audio with the following GStreamer pipeline:

Server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! rtpvorbispay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp, media=audio, clock-rate=44100, encoding-name=VORBIS, encoding-params=1, payload=96" ! rtpvorbisdepay ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

I get the following message from GStreamer:

WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVorbisDepay:rtpvorbisdepay0: Could not decode stream.
Additional debug info: gstrtpvorbisdepay.c(614): gst_rtp_vorbis_depay_process (): /GstPipeline:pipeline 0/GstRtpVorbisDepay:rtpvorbisdepay0: Could not switch codebooks

And I don't get any sound on the client. Can anyone help?

[EDIT:]

When I copy-paste the caps from the server side... It works! But among those caps there is a configuration parameter which looks really ugly ([link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylnCv.jpg)). I noticed that if I just delete this parameter it doesn't work anymore. Moreover I used gst-inspect on udpsrc and rtpvorbisdepay elements and there is nothing about this parameter. Can someone explain me what this parameter corresponds to? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: can you play with vlc(I think you would need [sdp](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Introduction_to_network_streaming_using_GStreamer)? In the link there is mentioned parameter config.. but not explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is Theora Vorbis thing.. those are some configuration parameters for initialization of decoder if I understand that properly..

> Theora makes the same controversial design decision that Vorbis made to
>   include the entire probability model for the DCT coecients and all the quan-
>   tization  parameters  in  the  bitstream  headers.   This  is  often  several  hundred
>   elds.   It  is  therefore  impossible  to  decode  any  frame  in  the  stream  without
>   having previously fetched the codec info and codec setup headers.

~ from [here](http://www.theora.org/doc/Theora.pdf)

some similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505790/gstreamer-rtp-streaming-webcam)